# Flutter: Make text widget appear onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm giving my users the option to sent in an email. Once they enter their email address, I would like to simply add the text "Email has been sent to `user@email.com`".

I'm not quite sure on how to do this, and was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have done so far, and where exactly you want this text to appear ?

Comment: @esentis it's a bit messy so I can't really crop anything out without something making sense. I was hoping for some conceptual explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, to work you need to have a boolean value that triggers your `Text` widget using `Visibility`. Suppose the boolean variable is `isEmailSent` and set its initial value to be `false`.

```
bool isEmailSent = false;
```

Now the user has entered his/her email address and then on `onTap` you must change the state of the boolean value like this:

```
onTap:(){
  setState((){
    isEmailSent = true;
  });
}
```

When the state has been changed then with the help of `Visibility` and `Text` widgets you could do something like this:

```
Visibility(
  visible: isEmailSent,
  child: Text(
    "Email has been sent to user@email.com"
  )
)
```

Now, whenever the isEmailSent is true your text will be visible else not.

**EDIT**

*How would I change the user@email.com to the input?*

Again you also need to have a String variable for this to work. This time the name of the variable will be `emailId`. Initially set its value as an empty string like this:

```
String emailId = "";
```

Then change the state of the variable using `setState`, like this:

```
setState((){
  emailId = _textController.text;  //where _textController is the controller of your input
});
```

Now inside your `Text` do something like this:

```
Text(
  "Email has been sent to "+emailId
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your explanation. How would I change the `user@email.com` to the input?

Comment: @someJoe121 check the edit. If you find it useful please upvote and mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create onTap() as the user enters the email address. in onTap define [**AlertDialog**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) that will give an popup dialog showing text  "Email has been sent to user@email.com "